# Smart Pointers pointing to new object

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr

I created a program like below

```
void Encode(shared_ptr<string>str)
{
    shared_ptr<string> n(new string());
        //I am creating the string pointed by n here by analyzing the string pointed by str 
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<str.get()<<" Func "<<str.use_count()<<" "<<n.get()<<" "<<n.use_count()<<endl;
    str=n;
    cout<<str.get()<<" Func "<<str.use_count()<<" "<<n.get()<<" "<<n.use_count()<<endl;
}

int main ()
{
    string s("aaabbbccd");
    shared_ptr<string> str(new string(s));
    Print(str);
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<str.get()<<"  Main "<<str.use_count()<<" "<<endl;
    Encode(str);
    cout<<str.get()<<" Main "<<str.use_count()<<" "<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    Print(str);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Since i am encoding the string ,so i do not want the original string after I  encode, I tried by writing the line `str=n` to do it thinking that this would make `str` point to the new string which I can use in my main program, but it is not correct as i am getting the original string only as output ,not the modified one.

I even checked using `.get()` function and it seems that it is pointing to the original string only.

Can anyone explain me why it is so and how can i make `str` to point to the new string?

Answer (score 1):

Your `Encode` function is passed a **copy** of the shared pointer.  And you're only modifying that copy.  Not the one in main.

```
void Encode(shared_ptr<string>str)
```

You should instead pass the pointer by *reference*.  Then it will *refer* to the same `shared_ptr` in main.

```
void Encode(shared_ptr<string> &str)
```

**As a side note**, it is usually a bad idea to call `shared_ptr::get()` because it produces a raw pointer that sidesteps the purpose of smart pointers.  Instead of `str.get()`, simply use `*str`.